# libcurl with HTTP response code always 0?

Tags: http, authorization, libcurl, xacml, abac

I am trying the libcurl  for the http post method to a server (PEP communication to PDP).

I tested the server with Postman and it works fine.

I adopted the  curl example from the link below for my testing:

https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/post-callback.html.

I modified the http header to match with those configured in the Postman setting.

However,  the HTTP response code is always 0.

The following are the codes I run for curl.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

static const char data[]  = "some XACML format";

 ...
int main(void)
{
   CURL *curl;
   CURLcode res;

   struct WriteThis wt;

   wt.readptr = data;
   wt.sizeleft = strlen(data);

   long  http_code= 0;
  /* In windows, this will init the winsock stuff */ 
  res = curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);
  /* Check for errors */ 
   if(res != CURLE_OK) {
     fprintf(stderr, "curl_global_init() failed: %s\n",
     curl_easy_strerror(res));
     return 1;
      }

  /* get a curl handle */ 
      curl = curl_easy_init();
     if(curl) {
  /* First set the URL that is about to receive our POST. */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, 
     "http://10.10.150.134:9443/api/identity/entitlement/decision/pdp");

    /* Now specify we want to POST data */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);

   /* we want to use our own read function */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, read_callback);

    /* pointer to pass to our read function */ 
   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, &wt);

    /* get verbose debug output please */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);


     struct curl_slist *chunk = NULL;
     chunk =curl_slist_append(chunk, "Accept:*/*");
     chunk =curl_slist_append(chunk, "Authorization:Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=");
     chunk =curl_slist_append(chunk, "Content-Type:application/xml");
     res = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, chunk);

     curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, (long)wt.sizeleft);
     res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
     res = curl_easy_getinfo(curl,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE,&http_code);


    if(res != CURLE_OK)
       fprintf(stdout, "curl_easy_perform() failed with HTTP code (%ld): %s\n",
           http_code,curl_easy_strerror(res));
    else {   
       fprintf(stdout, "curl_easy_perform() succeeded with HTTP code (%ld): %s\n",
         http_code,curl_easy_strerror(res));
}
     curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
   }
    curl_global_cleanup();
    return 0;
 }
```

The output of the above code is always as follows:

```
Trying 10.10.150.134...

*Connected to 10.10.150.134 (10.10.150.134) port 9443 (#0)

>POST /api/identity/entitlement/decision/pdp HTTP/1.1

Host: 10.10.150.134:9443

Accept:*/*

Authorization:Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=

Content-Type:application/xml

Content-Length: 1018

*We are completely uploaded and fine

*Connection #0 to host 10.10.150.134 left intact

"???"curl_easy_perform() succeeded with HTTP code (0): No error
```

"???" are some recognized characters... However, the HTTP code is always 0. I have googled this but none of the solution works for my case :(...

Comment: ancient libcurl version? Also, you're not showing us your code...

Comment: Hi, I think I have attached the codes in my question?

Comment: I can't see any problem (other than you using the old name, as its called `CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE`  since about a hundred years). Can you try if the command line version shows the code:  `curl -w '%{response_code}\n' curl.haxx.se`

Comment: Never mind. i figured it out now. I missed the "s" in the URL. It should be "https:\//10.10.150.134:9443/api/identity/entitlement/decision/pdp" instead of "http:\//10.10.150.134:9443/api/identity/entitlement/decision/pdp"... A missing letter costs me a week to find out.. what a pain..